Abel summability of an alternating sum
Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence taking values in the set $\{1,2\}$ and write $S_n=a_1+\cdots+a_n$ for the partial sum. Consider the alternating infinite sum $f(r)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^nr^{S_n}$. Clearly this function is bounded as $r\to1-$. My question is whether this series is Abel summable, that is, does the limit $\lim\limits_{r\to1-}f(r)$ exist?

why should it be summable? think of a choice of $a_n$ for which you get a limit (eg all $a_n=1$ where the limit is $-1/2$ and then think of a choice where the limit exists but is different eg the ones for which the odd exponents are $1,4,7..$ and the even ones are $3,6,9..$ where the limit is $-2/3$ and then think of mixing them, though keeping one set of choices (the ones where the difference between odd and even is $1$ always) for large chunks, and the other set of choices (where even is $2$ after odd but odd is $1$ after even) on other large chunks and see what you get for partial sums

if the chunks intersperse and increase massively in length, then you have a partial sum where all the chunks but the last are (very close) to $\pm 1$ for a given $r$ close but not too close to $1$ so getting zero plus very small error if you end on an even, while the last chunk actually mimics its infinite sum so is close to either $-2/3$ or $-1/2$ etc

@Conrad can you be more precise on your last sentence? I think the last chunk mimics its infinite sum only when $r\to1$, am I right?

For each partial sum as above (bunch of chunks alternating and each increasing very fast in number of terms) you need to take an $r_n$ close enough to $1$ for which the last chunk mimics its partial sum but the previous ones are $\pm 1$ - say you have the alternating the chunk last, then the partial sum will be an $r^{N_n}\frac{1-r^{N_{n+1}}}{1-r}$ so you take $r^{N_n}$ close to $1$ and $r^{N_{n+1}}$ close to $0$ which you can do if $N_{n+1}>> N_n^{N_n}$ for example

So for example you can take $r_n$ st $r_n^{N_n}>1-1/N_n^2$ hence all terms before $N_n$ are $\pm 1$ with error at most $1/N_n^2$ so the sum is zero with error $1/N_n$, while also we choose $N_{n+1}$ large enough so $r_n^{N_{n+1}-N_n} <1/N_n$ hence the last chunk sums to $-1/2$ with error $1/N_n$; same for the other choice of last chunk now from $N_{n+1}$ chosen so getting $r_{n+1}$ as above and then getting $N_{n+2}$ so now the last chunk is $-2/3$ plus small error etc

@Conrad let's see if I understand correctly (write $f_N(r)$ for the partial sum of the first $N$ terms and $E_N(r)=f(r)-f_N(r)$), we finally get two sequences $N_1<<N_2<<N_3\cdots$ and $r_1<r_2<r_3<\cdots\to1$ such that $f_{N_{2n+1}}(r_{2n+1})$ is close to (say) $-1/2$ while $f_{N_{2n}}(r_{2n})$ is close to $-2/3$. Moreover $E_{N_n}(r_n)<<1$. So this produces a sequence $f(r_1),f(r_2),\cdots$ which alternates between $-1/2$ and $-2/3$. This is indeed a nice counterexample! Thanks a lot!

Yes that's correct - in general Abel convergence is fairly rare as you need some regularity on the coefficients

@Conrad do you happen to know some references of results on Abel convergence, in particular the regularity you mentioned? (sorry for taking you so much time).

I would look into Hardy's book on divergent series - not sure anything deeper in this area has been done since
